# Is there a generalisation of the Polya Enumeration Theorem to actions of wreath products?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $X$, $Y$ be sets and let G, H be groups which act on $X$, $Y$ (respectively). Denote the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ by $X^Y$. I will use $f$ for functions in $X^Y$ and $g, h$ for elements of $G, H$, respectively.

As I understand it, the Polya Enumeration Theorem allows us to count the number of orbits of functions in $X^Y$ up to equivalence via the action of $G$ by:

$ g \cdot f(x) = f(x ^ g)$ for all $x \in X$.

There is also a generalization of Polya Enumeration Theorem (Frank Harary and Ed Palmer call it the Power Group Enumeration Theorem) which allows us to count functions in $X^Y$ up to equivalence via the following action of the direct product $G \times H$:

$(g, h) \cdot f(x) = h \cdot f(x ^ g)$ for all $x \in X$.

I want to ask whether the orbits of the wreath product $G \wr H = G \ltimes H^d$ (where $d = |X|$ is the degree of $G$) can be counted with respect to the following action

$(g, (h_1, \dots, h_d)) \cdot (y_1, \dots, y_d) = (h_1 \cdot y_{1^{g^{-1}}}, \dots, h_d \cdot y_{d^{g^{-1}}})$.

---

*Harary, Frank; Palmer, Edgar M.*, [**Graphical enumeration**](https://oeis.org/A102190), New York-London: Academic Press. XIV, 271 p. (1973). [ZBL0266.05108](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0266.05108).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point with some useful references is

[Enumeration under two representations of the wreath product](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02392038.pdf) by Palmer and Robinson.

Comment: Also open-access at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485889789 .

Comment: Not just a starting point -- I think it's the whole answer. The action of $A\left[B\right]$ on $Y^X$ in Theorem 2 of that paper is exactly the action of $G \wr H$ on $X^Y$ in the original post (with $G$, $H$, $X$ and $Y$ renamed as $A$, $B$, $Y$ and $X$).